# Warning: Unable to write "..." file (Error code: UNKNOWN). Livereload option

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I want to use **grunt-contrib-watch** with **livereload** option. If I change something in the file before I opened the browser then everything compiles right.

Once I opened the browser it no longer rewrites files. Maybe this problem is because I'm using Windows OS?

Run server> while (true) {Changing Code - It compiles fine} > Run browser

Run server> Run browser > Changing code - Get an Unknown error.

> Running "fest:templates" (fest) task
>   Compiling "templates/game.xml" to
>   "public_html/js/tmpl/game.js"...Warning: Unable to write
>   "public_html/js/tmpl/game.js" file (Error code: UNKNOWN). Use --force
>   to continue.

Here is my **Gruntfile.js**:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    shell: { /*grunt-shell*/
      options: { /*настройка задачи*/
        stdout: true,
        stderr: true
      },
      server: {
        command: 'java -jar 2dContra-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar 8080'
      }
    },
    fest: { /*grunt-fest*/
      templates: { /*Подзадача*/
        files: [{ /* указание файлов группами */
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'templates', /* исходная директория */
          src: '*.xml', /* имена шаблонов */
          dest: 'public_html/js/tmpl' /* результирующая директория */
        }],
        options: { /* формат функции шаблона */
          template: function (data) {
            return grunt.template.process( /* присваиваем функцию шаблона */
                'var <%= name %>Tmpl = <%= contents %> ;',
                {data: data}
            );
          }
        }
      }
    },
    watch: { /*grunt-watch*/
      fest: {/*Подзадача*/
        files: ['templates/*.xml'], /* Следим за шаблонами */
        tasks: ['fest'], /* Перекомпилировать */
        options: {
          interrupt: true,
          atBegin: true /* Запустить задачу при старте */
        }
      },
      server: {/*Подзадача*/
        files: [ /* Следим за JS */
          'public_html/js/**/*.js',
          'public_html/css/**/*.css'
        ],
        options: {
          livereload: true /* автоматическая перезагрузка */
        }
      }
    },
    concurrent: { /*grunt-concurrent*/
      target: ['watch', 'shell'],
      options: {
        logConcurrentOutput: true /* Вывод процесса */
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-fest');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['concurrent']);

};
```

Save my life. I would like to work and don't type "grunt" every time when I changed the code.

Comment: Does the directory exist? Does the user that runs the code have permissions to write there?

Comment: @Robbert, as i said before it works fine if the browser isn't running, after that strange things happen
I started my IDE(IDEA) with Administrator permission many times, but it didn't help me